# Error C2504: 'Vending': base class undefined

Tags: c++

Alright, so I have two classes, Vending and Payment. Payment is the child of Vending. I keep getting the "base class undefined" error in my code.

Here are the two header files:

```
//Parent class (Vending.h)
#ifndef VENDING_H

#define VENDING_H

#include "Main.h";

namespace Vending
{
    class Vending
    {
    public:
        Vending();
        Vending(int);
        void setRequiredAmount(int);
        int getRequiredAmount();


    protected:
        int selectedItem;
        int requiredAmount;
    };
}
#endif VENDING_H

//child class (Payment.h)
#ifndef PAYMENT_H
#define PAYMENT_H

#include "Vending.h"

namespace Vending
{
    class Payment : public Vending
    {
    public:
        Payment(int);
        int getEnteredAmount();
        void setEnteredAmount(int);

        protected:
        int enteredAmount;


    };
}
#endif PAYMENT_H
```

It would be greatly appreciated if I can get some help to resolve this error

Comment: Why is Payment.h included in Vending.h?

Comment: took it out, still does not solve the issue

Comment: and what's `#include "Main.h";`? and `#endif VENDING_H`

Comment: After consulting my crystal ball, Main.h includes Payment.h and Vending.h doesn't use anything from Main.h, so it shouldn't include it.

Comment: @billz, The `#endif VENDING_H` is unconventional, but it expands to `#endif`. Good catch on the semicolon, though. I didn't even see that.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting. Implementing empty constructors and putting both definitions in the same file compiles fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You say Main.h includes Payment.h, which DOES lead to circular dependencies. Read this post for additional information: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?288147-C2504-Base-class-undefined-(other-posts-have-no-solution)&p=919112#post919112

You need to rethink your project properly, conditions like this should not happen. Simply try to remove the #include "Main.h" from the Vending.h, and compile Payment.cpp...